In dual column mode, the table is too long
My article is in dual column mode. The table is too long, and a single column exceeds the page length. How can I make it automatically push to the second column，
this warning：
LaTeX: Float too large for page by 39.31897pt.
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{NOTATIONS}
\label{notationTable}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
    \hline
    Notation        & Definition\\ \hline
    $n$             & Number of users/tasks\\
    .......
    long long content.............
    ......   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


Use \begin{table*} instead of \begin{table}, which spanned to both the columns

You could use longtblr from tabularray:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mwe}% <-- for testing purpose only
\begin{document}
\blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption={NOTATIONS},
  label={notationTable},
  ]{
  colspec={lp{5cm}},
  hline{1,2}={solid},
  rowhead=1,
  row{1}={abovesep=3pt},
  }
  Notation        & Definition\\ 
  $n$             & Number of users/tasks\\
  $a$             & something\\
  $b$             & something\\
  $c$             & something\\
  $d$             & something\\
  $e$             & something\\
  $f$             & something\\
  $g$             & something\\
  $h$             & something\\
  $i$             & something\\
  $j$             & something\\
  $k$             & something\\
  $l$             & something\\
  $m$             & something\\
  $n$             & something\\
  $o$             & something\\
  $p$             & something\\
  $q$             & something\\
  $r$             & something\\
  $s$             & something\\
  $t$             & something\\
  $u$             & something\\
  $v$             & something\\
  $w$             & something\\
  $x$             & something\\
  $y$             & something\\
  $z$             & something\\
\end{longtblr}
\blindtext% <-- for testing purpose only
\end{document}


